# Get all posts and check if user liked each post

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to create an Eloquent query that fetches all posts and checks if the user liked each of those posts.

I have the following models:

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Like');
    }
}
```

**Like.php**:

```
class Like extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'likes';
}
```

And your typical `User` model as well.

My DB structure is the following:

`posts` table:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | message |
+----+---------+---------+
```

`users` table:

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
```

`likes` table:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Right now, my query only returns all posts, but how can I modify it to return all posts *and* check if the user liked each post?

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', function()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return View::make('index')->with('posts', $posts);
}));
```

Thanks!

Comment: you would need to do that on a per post basis.. Or create a custom raw query using joins etc..

Answer (score 1):

What about a left join between the posts table and the likes table, filtering by the actual user's id?

```
$post = DB::table('post')
                 ->select(DB::raw('message, likes.user_id IS NOT NULL as liked'))
                 ->leftJoin('likes', 'users_id', '=', 'likes.user_id')
                 ->where('likes.user_id', '=', $curent_user_id)  
                 ->get();
```

I have no way to test it now, but I hope it might give you some inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the `likes` with the post for that specific user. Try this..

```
Post::with(['likes' => function() use ($user_id) { $q->where('user_id','=', $user_id); }])->all();
```

It will return blank array if user haven't like the post.