# how to use leftJoin on sequelize findAll method

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

How would i be able to use sequelize findAll to check if each post has been liked by the current user.

the `where` query filters through the posts array objects. It needs to check if the current user liked a post, but still get all data.

Would i need to do a left join ? `where` `userId === req.session.user.id`

[Get all posts and check if user liked each post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059948/get-all-posts-and-check-if-user-liked-each-post)

I'm using sequelize, and postgres. Its pretty much just sql .

How should i go about achieving this using sequelize

what the posts structure looks like

[image]

Take for example this code, this is laravel app i made, i want the same implementation in sequelize

**php(Example)**

```
public function getPosts( )
    {
        $posts = Post::with('user')
                     ->with(['likes' => function ($query) {
                                $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                                $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                            }])
                      ->with(['comments' => function($query) {

                            $query->with('user');
                        }])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();
        $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
        { 
            $user = auth()->user();
            if($user->can('delete', $post)) {
                $post['deletable'] = true;
            }
            if($user->can('update', $post)) {
                $post['update'] = true;
            }
            // $comment = new Comment();
            $post['likedByMe'] = $post->likes->count() == 0 ? false : true;
            $post['likesCount'] = Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get()->count();
            $post['createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();
            $post['createdAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();

            return $post;


        });
        return response()->json($data); 
    }
```

**post.controller.js**

```
 getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    // use async/await here
    const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        // limit the likes based on the logged in user
        {
          model: models.Likes
        }
      ],
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: 6
    });
    // i dont think this is the right approach. 
    posts.forEach(post => {
      post.Likes.forEach(like => {
        console.log(like.userId);
        if (like.userId === req.session.user.id) {
          post.setDataValue("likedByMe", true);
        } else {
          post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
        }
      });
    });

    return res.json(posts);
```

**post.js**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        postContent: DataTypes.STRING,
        liked: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false,
            get: function () {
                return this.getDataValue('Likes').length ? true : false;
            }
        },
        likeCounts: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
            validate: {
                min: 0,
            }
        },
        authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {});
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: "author",
            foreignKey: "authorId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
        Post.hasMany(models.Likes, {
            foreignKey: "resourceId",
            timestamps: false,
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return Post;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this forEach statement helped identifying if the current user has liked the post or not.

```
 getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    // use async/await here
    const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        // limit the likes based on the logged in user
        {
          model: models.Likes
        }
      ],
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: 6
    });

    posts.forEach(post => {
      if (post.Likes.length === 0) {
        post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
      }
      post.Likes.forEach(like => {
        console.log(like.userId);
        if (like.userId === req.session.user.id) {
          post.setDataValue("likedByMe", true);
        } else {
          post.setDataValue("likedByMe", false);
        }
      });
    });

    return res.json(posts);
  },
```